# Поворот части изображения в PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, rotate

Возможно ли в PictureBox часть изображения развернуть на 90 градусов?

В моем случае по расписанию из datagridview рисуется график по содержащимся данным тарифных зон. Тарифная зона может иметь минимальную продолжительность - 10 минут, при этом происходит наложение текста. Мне необходимо в процессе рисования данных времени (событие Paint) отобразить надпись вертикально.

[image: Тарифное расписание]

Comment: Покажите код, который рисует надпись горизонтально для начала. А так, загляните в [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-vertical-text-on-a-windows-form?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Информация из документации помогла, спасибо. Код выложу позже, как исправлю.